# to store date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I need to store date in mysql (without time). User inputs date in input box like yyyy-mm-dd, may be later fomat could change.
Could you please tell what is good way to store date in mongodb (without time), we'd use   DATE type in mysql? Now whe I need to store date and time I use mongdb date type.
And store it like this:

```
$data['ADDED'] = new MongoDate(time());
```

And display them:

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['ADDED']->sec);
```

When I use only date I store them as string like: yyyy-mm-dd (I validate date before storing it to make sure it's correct date). I'll need to find by date something like this:

```
dateField <(>) somedate
```

Do you think it's acceptable to store date as string in mongodb? How do you usually store date in mongodb?

Comment: What is the real question and what is the point of your question. MongoDB has a type for date + time. Why don't you use it? What's the problem?

Comment: I need only date, not date and time. Mongo date type store number of seconds from Unix Epoch, so it store date and time, I need only date. Do you think storing date as string as I described is acceptable. I would appreciate you read my question with attention.

Comment: @Oleg: Just store the datetime and when you need it, only use the date portion of that. I guess this would be in sync with POLS (principle of least surprise).

Comment: Then set the hours-minutes-second to 00:00:00...and here you go: you have a valid date representation...why is this not good enough for you?

Comment: If you need something different: use strings and use ISO format in order to make dates stored as ISO strings comparable and sortable.

Comment: I tried to use to store as strings because I didn't have format date before displays, not matter how many date fields I have in document, I could them display as it is.

Comment: I try to see cons of storing date as string, as oppose to storing in as MongoDate. The pro is that I don't have to format data after extracting from the database.

Comment: It seems to me it would be useful if we had type similar to DATE type in mysql.

Comment: You know your options. Make your choice...nobody else cares. If you want a DATE type, ask 10gen.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not have a DATE type. It instead has a `ISODate` type. This is just as good for storing "without" time as I will explain.

So you can use `MongoDate` like so:

```
$date = new MongoDate(); // Denotes today, just like the date() function
```

Now to store without time you can just fake it by making PHP only set a date, as such the default time will be `00:00:00` (I should note this does mean a time is actually stored just as `00:00:00`):

```
$date = new MongoDate(strtotime('2012-04-23')); // strtotime for fun
```

And then you can query by just the date part like:

```
find(array('date' => new MongoDate(strtotime('2012-04-23'))));
```

And you can now query as though you don't have a time since the time will equal what you put in: `00:00:00`.

Of course this is just one way of fixing it.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean use MongoDate instead gmdate? In my example I use MongoDate, I tried to store time as utc and display it as utc time.

Comment: Oh Yea sorry I only saw the gmdate bit. Well you used `time()` there that takes both the date and the "time" into account which is why it didn't work for you. If you use the method I displayed it will work.

Comment: What's the difference between  new MongoDate(time()); and new MongoDate()?

Comment: Nothing both will take the current time you have

Comment: As I described before I used it when I had to store date and time, something like added created or so.

Comment: Yes...wait am I missing something here? That line I state is just to show the `MongoDate` object the answer lies after that line

Comment: Pardon, I didn't quite understand you last remark. Could you please explain?

Comment: What did you mean by the comment before "As I described before I used it when I had to store date and time," ? That's what my last comment was in reply to

Comment: I meant date the code in my question reflected my working with datetime type, when I need only date I stored it as strings.

Comment: Ah don't do that, storing date as strings is a bad idea, use the date helper making the time `00:00:00`. Using strings will be bad for performance and storage here and querying abilities.

Comment: I also mentitions that date will be inouted by users, so your code won't work, datetime fields I filled my self, like created, added fields. Date filled should be inputed by users and then may be queried by this date as well.

Comment: Coudl you please explain why will storing date as string will be bad for querying abilities and performance and storage?

Comment: Relying on the user to input a valid date is not good practice, you should validate their input and convert it to a true date and store it as a true date in a single format.

Comment: I have to get date from users. I get in format: yyyy-mm-dd. I validate that date is correct and store only if it's correct.

Comment: One of reasons I used stringd because I didn't have to format them before displaying, I can display them as it is.

Comment: Fro example, for datetime fields when I display them I had to format them every time: echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['ADDED']->sec);

Comment: Yea I would say that is why I would use MongoDate for one is because of ability to customise its display, plus what if you want timezones? Also the index would be much bigger using string than the date object and so too would the values which would effect performance and storage costs also you will need to use regex on this possibly (query dependant) which means slow queries probably also quite a few other things like that string comparison is slower in this case but that should be enough to get my point across

Comment: I meant that if to use mongo date type it's necessary to format date, one can't diplay them as it is. In some cases it seems simpler. But maybe it put limations as well.

Comment: I try to store utc time on database to avoid issues with timezones.

Comment: I don't quite understand why to use regex for queries with date if to store date as string. If we store for exmaple it as yyyy-mm-dd and we need operations: ==, !=, <, > we don't need regex, right?

Comment: So long as you are always querying by the full date no, as I said it is query dependant but as a programmer I always take future compatibility into account to produce the best possible scenario of further development. It is part of the core of being a programmer.

Comment: "In some cases it seems simpler. But maybe it put limations as well." How so? I do not see the limitations

Comment: I mean here: storing as string make displaying data from collection simpler as it's not necessary to format them, this was one of reason I used them. But storing as string maybe could put limitations at the same time that date type doesn't have.

Comment: I try to understand tradeoff between storing as string and simpler displaying (we can display as it is) and to see limiation that storing date as string has vs storing as date type with 0s in time fields.

Comment: Hmm I suppose if you see having to feed the field value through some global function in PHP to display the dates a limitation, however it will cost you database side as I said. The date type for one will cost index and storage and as you know it is your indexes that make queries faster. Evne though you might have to format manually client side you will need to house more resources server-side for this.

Comment: Right now I don't plan to use index on this fields, it's hardly possible. In collection I store info about people and people belongs to some list, each list can have different fields. All documents has LISTID, EMAIL and some other feld that each document has, and there fields unique for each list (there can be added/deleted by users). For example, some fileds could have field DATE. In this case in collection it will be: EMAIL, LISTID, ...,fiedl_id_of_DATE_field: value. I query data from some list, for example bases on some conditions that user fields of the list. I have index LIST_ID, EMAIL.

Comment: What's the size of date type in mongodb?

Comment: I suppose if you never ever query this value then of course you will never need an index which does omit that. I am unsure about the exact measurements of the date type in index however the basis of the date type is a milisecond integer from the last epoch (1970).

Comment: Quering by this field for example date (is possible), but I can't add index to the fiels and benefit from it, because each list can have each unique indexes and it's impossible to put indexes on all of them. So I have indexes on fields that are common to all sites, so in many cases mongodb will extract from index for example LIST_ID pointer to date in collection and will have to scan all of them, most lists are not more that 10s of thousands of people. I don't have other choice in this case.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot advise on your schema since I only know it from you describing it but possibly there might be something that can be done better there if you have no choice but you not use indexOnly cursors. The mian problem is that even over 100K string values (I get this in SQL as well without an index) you are starting to look at speed problems so even though you whittle it down with a LIST_ID index it might not be sufficient, but I cannot dictate on it.

Comment: In collection very many lists can be stored and it's not realistic to make indexes for all custom fields. For example, if there are 100K lists and each list can have several custom fields.

Comment: Well the lists are basically kery value stores defined by the user? There is a way to index key-value stores without too excessive space and resources being used up. But yea that's if I am right about your structure, there are a couple of examples out there, on this site even of using MongoDB indexes for key-value stores.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: So I assume you have: `{list: {userField1: somevalue, userField2: somevalue}}` or you have an array of lists within the `list` field. Atm making an index, as you said, on those field isn't very feasible, one  of the problem is the amount of field name and values etc but if you were to change to: `list: {k: userField1, v: somevalue}` it might produce a structure you can index. As for uniqueness on the list etc, I would enforce this with addToSet rather than an index.

Comment: My structure is like: EMAIL, FNAME, LNAME, LIST_ID, STATUS ...,Custom fields specific for each list (the descriptions of them are store in mysql database now). Now mostly it used indexes LIST_ID, EMAIL and LIST_ID, STATUS. The quesry are usually like thisl db.collection.find({LISTID: id, STATUS: status, possible other conditions based on custom fields which are not very often now})

Comment: Ah ok your limiting by more than list_id, it might be ok then, but I should stress I cannot say for certain so I would test your queries first but I guess if you got an ok speed in SQL using the same structure and index pattern it should work in MongoDB.

Comment: Custom fields are stored in collection like: FIELD_ID1: value1, FIELD_ID2: value2. Some of fiels can have multple values (stored as array)

Comment: On this stage I store in mysql only people as they can have custom fields, I have a version that used mysql for storing people using EAV, but it seems rather complex.

Comment: Custom fields can be added or deleted by users. For example if it's deleted from list, I also delete values for this fields in mongodb collection using FIELD_ID which is the name of field.

Comment: Yes, I saw recently about possible storing custom fields like key page in mongodb, like: {k: field_id, v: value}, I'm not sure I can benefit from it now. In any case index by k,v is not sufficient here, I need info about LIST_ID as well, I use mostly index with LIST_ID now.

Comment: But this idea seems interesting too, I'll think about it later.

Comment: One of the main probelms is that I have to gather all fields to display each record (constant and custom fields).